# How to know whether an Android foreground service was started by OS or some user action?

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

I have a requirement to keep a service running (which fetches latest location updates) regardless of whether my Android app is running or closed.

I have finally used a notification based foreground service for this purpose, and it does this job well unless and until the app is closed. 
So what happens is:

- when the app is running on UI or in the background, the service perfectly fetches the location.
- when the app is closed, i.e. swiped off from recent apps, the service gets restarted somehow and fails to fetch location updates.

Now, I want to understand whether that service is started by my application or by the Android OS. Is there any way to figure out?

I tried the following, but the problem is that `intent` isn't always null when started by service.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i(Constants.TAG + this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside onStartCommand");

    if (null == intent) {

        Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Service was stopped and automatically restarted by the system.");
        BackgroundTaskHandler.startLocationMonitorServiceBySelf(this, 20 * 1000); // start after 20 sec
        Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Stopped self. Restarting again via alarm.");
        stopSelf();

    } else {
        // Other piece of code to setup location client 
        // and configure notification intent
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if the intent is null, you can be more specific and check if the intent contains an extra set by your activity.

In your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourService.class);
intent.putExtra("IntentFlag", "MainActivity");
```

In your service:

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("IntentFlag").equals("MainActivity"))
{
    //Service started by activity
}
```

Hope this helps!